# Data can be read to the console, but is not available

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```
  setup () {
    const route = useRoute()
    const getForm = async () => {
      await db.collection('forms').doc(route.params.id).onSnapshot(async (doc) => {
        const { title, content, createdAt } = await doc.data()
        console.log(title, content, createdAt)
      })
    }
    getForm()
  }
```

I can represent title, content, createdAt in console through getForm function.
However, {{title}} is not available on template.
What should I do to read the imported data? I use firestore and vue3.

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In setup()
I need edit title to { title.value}